# Create function in c# that returns value

Tags: c#

I want create function in c# WPF that returns 10 digit values. It contains as below

1. One Digit (Static) ->  'G'
2. Two Digit (Dynamic) -> '19' Of current Year
3. Two Digit (Dynamic) -> '04' of Current Month
4. Five Digit (Dynamic) -> '00284' <- It is returned from sql table. The length of this must be fixed.

The return value for above code is 'G190400284' (I want this value as return)
if my five digit(4.) value is supposed to 1 then it's returns 'G1904000001'

Comment: Please help me or please give me suggestions. please

Comment: and if the 5th digit is not 1 then what?

Comment: sir 5th digit value is came from sql table id field which is auto increment. so it's value is must

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question.. can you try to explain a b it better?

Comment: Sir, My question is that total length of return value is 10 character. it contains first only one character is fixed and its G, then two character of current year means 19, then two character of current month 04, then five digit comes from my sql table's id field

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: suppose my first record for this year and this month then return value must be like G190400001, If I enter second record then return value is G190400002, if new record number is suppose 281 then return value is G190400281.

Comment: I mean to show your code attempt. How did you try to write your code?

Comment: so what you want is something that concatenates  "GyyMM" +the value from DB ?

Comment: so what you want is something that concatenates "GyyMM" +the value from DB ? -->Yes Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CreateString(1));
        Console.WriteLine(CreateString(284));
    }


    public static string CreateString(int id)
    {
        var n = DateTime.Now;
        return "G" + n.Year.ToString().Substring(2,2) + n.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + id.ToString().PadLeft(5,'0');
    }

}

// This returns
// G190400001
// G190400284
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/oteEpe

Comment: How do I do it dynamic?

Comment: sir above functions value I want to display in my label text. So how do i do it?

Comment: mylabel.Text = CreateString(1); ? I this is already causing you troubles i suggest to start with c# basics before getting into database and ui stuff.